# WPF reference style in resource dictionary and use triggers

Tags: wpf, triggers, styles, resourcedictionary

I have a `Style` defined in a resource dictionary that applies to
all `ComboBox` controls.  Within the `ComboBox` control, I reference the style like so:

`Style="{DynamicResource MyComboBoxStyle}"`

This works ok.

I want to be able to add some triggers to some of the `ComboBox` controls.

What is a good way to use the `Style` referenced as a dynamic resource yet still be able to add `Trigger`s to some of the `ComboBox` controls?

Answer (score 1):

---

**Update**:
After re-reading the question, I realize this isn't exactly what the OP was  asking about. I could delete this, but perhaps it will be useful to someone who stumbles upon this question.

---

Here's an example, with a xaml resource dictionary defining the template and the triggers, along with a window that references that resource and applies the style.

It may help someone looking into using templates and triggers:

**My resource named "Style1.xaml"**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TonyTemplate" TargetType="Button">
    <Border Name="Border" 
            BorderBrush="Orange" 
            BorderThickness="3" 
            CornerRadius="2" 
            Background="Ivory" 
            TextBlock.Foreground="Black">
        <Grid>
            <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Chartreuse" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkKhaki" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**My MainWindow Code xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Style1.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Width="100" Height="50" 
                Template="{StaticResource TonyTemplate}" 
                Content="Click me"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new styles for the `ComboBox` controls that you want to apply triggers to, and use the [`BasedOn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx) property on the new style to set their base style.

Comment: I get the following error when I attempt to do that:
 A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the 'BasedOn' property of type 'Style'.

Comment: Why are you using DynamicResource, anyway? StaticResource should work for setting the Style.

Comment: The Style is located in a separate module (using CAL), so I have to specify DynamicResource in order to use it.

Comment: So basically this hasn't been solved yet... I wanted an answer as well.